# jQuery UI Draggable & Droppable in Vue JS Component with Dynamic Data

Tags: vue.js, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable, vuedraggable

I have a view component where I want to be able to drag certain elements (`.draggable`) onto other certain elements (`.droppable`) like this:

[image: example]

I can set it up for static `<div>` elements in `mounted()` like this:

```
mounted(){
  $('.draggable').draggable({
    revert: true
  })

  $('.droppable').droppable({
    hoverClass: 'drop-hover',
    drop: function(){
      console.log('-= dropped =-')
    }
  })  
}
...
<div class="droppable">Drop Here</div>
<div class="draggable">Drag Me</div>
<div class="draggable">Drag Me</div>
<div class="draggable">Drag Me</div>
```

But when I want to do this on dynamically in Vue JS with `v-for` then the jQuery UI bindings seem to get lost:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items">
  <div class="droppable">{{ item.name }}</div>
  <div v-for="(folder, index) in item.folders" class="draggable">{{ folder.name }}</div>
</div>
```

I can no longer drag the `.draggable` items.

As I understand it, jQuery Draggable/Droppable does not work with `.on` since I suspect one of the issues is that my DOM elements are generated after jQuery is initialized. I tried wrapping my jQuery code in `this.$nextTick(() => { ... })` but it still doesn't work.

I have also looked at [Vue.Draggable](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable) but I want the drag and drop without the simultaneous reordering.

Is it possible to combine jQuery Draggable/Droppable with dynamic data in Vue JS?

Comment: Do you have any error in the console? I'm not able to reproduce (https://codepen.io/rd3n/pen/OJyXPVb). Probably related to another part of your code not shown here. Which versions of Vue, jQuery and jQuery-ui are you using? Can you provide a reproduction example?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I don't have any errors. I think one of the differences is that I'm setting the `items` data from another component, so the `mounted()` method has already fired. If I set the `items` in the `data()` method statically like you have shown, it works.

Comment: hi, have you solve the problem? coz i also want to use droppable as well in vue js, but i got error  `$(...).droppable is not a function`